# VS Code include the commit descriptions from merged branches like `git merge --log`

Tags: visual-studio-code, merge

Edit: The duplicate question does NOT reference the use of VS Code, only git.  This is *within* VS Code doing merges, there is no way to include the commit message of merged commits. Or is there? That is the crux of this question.

**When using VS Code**, the "source control" panel or "Git Graph", to handle merges it only creates a generic "merging branchA into branchB" message.

I want to create a commit message as if I had passed the `--log` option into `git merge`.

> --log[=<n>]
> In addition to branch names, populate the log message with one-line descriptions from at most <n> actual commits that are being merged.

How can I use VS Code to do merges as usual while also specifying this option?